# XCode line breaks - don't truncate label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a label in Xcode, and when the text is long, I don't want it to truncate, but I want the remaining text to go into a new line. I made room for 3 lines, but again, it's only truncating. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
yourLabel.numberOfLines=0;
```

note: it is deprecated in ios6, then use:

```
NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
```

Comment: With what should I replace yourLabel? I used Xcode 2 or 3 times in total, and I don't know much about it. Should I first assign a class or an ID to the label? Or what?

Comment: `yourLabel` is the outlet to the UILabel

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the effect by also specifying the number of lines I wanted to appear

```
[self.label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.label setNumberOfLines:3];
[self.label sizeToFit];
```